# Is $X(t)=B_1(t)\,B_2(t)$ a martingale?

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, conditional-expectation

I want to check if $X(t)=B_1(t)\,B_2(t)$ is a martingale with respect to the filtration $F(t)$, where $B_1(t)$ and $B_2(t)$ are two independent Brownian motions.

For this I need to see if: $\mathbb{E}[X(t)|F(s)]=X(s)$. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: From the tag (brownian-motion) I assume that $B_1$ and $B_2$ are supposed to be standard Brownian motion? Also, I suppose $F(t)$ is the natural filtration for $X(t)$?

Comment: Yes they are. I fixed the post.

Comment: Hint: What do you know about the measurability of the increments $B_k(t)-B_k(s)$?

Comment: It is independent of filtration F(s), then its expected value equals to zero.

Comment: Thus? $ $ $ $ $ $

Answer (score 0):

I finally knew how to do it:

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[X(t)|F(s)] &= \mathbb{E}[B_1(t)B_2(t)|F(s)]\\
&=\mathbb{E}[(B_1(t)-B_1(s)+B_1(s))\,(B_2(t)-B_2(s)+B_2(s)|F(s)]\\
&=\mathbb{E}[(B_1(t)-B_1(s))(B_2(t)-B_2(s))+B_2(s)(B_1(t)-B_1(s))+B_1(s)(B_2(t)-B_2(s))+B_1(s)B_2(s)|F(s)]\\
&=B_2(s)B_1(s)\\
&=X(s)
\end{align}
Thus it is a martingale.

We have used the fact that:

$$\mathbb{E}[B(s)|F(s)]=B(s)\mathbb{E}[1|F(s)]=B(s),$$ because $B(s)$ is $F(s)-$measurable. And:

$$\mathbb{E}[B(t)-B(s)|F(s)]=\mathbb{E}[B(t)-B(s)]=0,$$ since, for $0\leq s\leq t$:

\begin{align}
B(t)-B(s)&=\sum_{i=s+1}^tY_i,
\end{align} where Y is a random variable, so $B(t)-B(s)$ is independent of filtration $F(s)$, and by definition the expected value of brownian motion increments is equal to zero.

Comment: "Using the fact that: $\mathbb{E}[X_t-X_s|F(s)]=\mathbb{E}[X_t-X_s]=0$" ?? Why? How?

Comment: It was a typo, I meant B instead of X.

Comment: OK, but it is unclear whether you know why the steps in your answer are correct or not. Rewrite?

Comment: I didn't get what you mean this time. Please feel free to improve my answer where you feel it needs to be clearer. Thanks @Did

Comment: You first: **why the fourth "=" sign** in the displayed equation in your answer?

Comment: I used the property of linearity of conditional expectation, then the property of independence of the Brownian motion increments regarding the filtration $F(s)$, and finally taking out what is known: $\mathbb{E}[XY|X]=X\mathbb{E}[Y|X]$

Comment: And if I should add that if X and Y independent random variables then $cov(X,Y)=0$, thus $\mathbb{E}[XY]=\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]$

Comment: Thus... if you want to present what is usually called a proof... these crucial parts of the argument should be in your answer. Note that at present the modified version is even slightly misleading since you mention two easy reasons, namely $E(B_s\mid F_s)=B_s$ and $E(B_t-B_s\mid F_s)=0$ but omit a more involved one which is also quite necessary. Again: **Write down a bona fide proof** and everybody will be happy...